# Размещение текстового поля не по центру объекта View

Tags: android, view, mobile-development

Здравствуйте!
Можно ли разместить текстовое поле в произвольной области объекта View или текст всегда располагается по середине объекта? Например, я хочу чтобы текстовое поле было в правом нижнем углу элемента TextView.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используй [RelativeLayout](http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/layout/relativelayout.php)

```
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
```